# Multicast packet seen in Wireshark, but not received by user program (Windows and Linux)

Tags: ruby, linux, networking, multicast

I'm trying to detect a network connected device using multicast from a Ruby program. I've sniffed the network traffic from the official detection program and found that the computer sends out a packet to 225.0.0.37:12345 and the device responds on 225.0.0.38:12346. The device is connected to a local network consisting of a Netgear switch, a Windows computer and a Linux computer. I've made my program to send out an identical packet as the official program does.

The problem I have is that the response is never received, neither by my program nor the official detection program. Using Wireshark I can clearly see the device responding without fail and the packet clearly makes it to my Linux computer which I run Wireshark on, but neither the official program running on the Windows computer, nor my own Ruby program running on the Linux computer gets the response.

Both my computers have two network adapters, one connected to the same local switch and one connected to another switch which is then connected up to a large LAN with internet access. I've tried using a different brand switch between the computers, but it made no difference.

I've searched far and wide on Internet and haven't found anything to solve my issue. I appreciate any help I can get.

Here are the relevant packets captured with tcpdump, the first is sent from my program and the second is the response from the device:

```
13:30:25.773019 IP 192.168.0.1.12345 > 225.0.0.37.12345: UDP, length 15
13:30:25.773770 IP 192.168.0.125.39129 > 225.0.0.38.12346: UDP, length 228
```

Here is a (simplified) snippet from my program:

```
MULTICAST_SEND_ADDRESS = '225.0.0.37'
MULTICAST_SEND_PORT = 12345
MULTICAST_RESPONSE_ADDRESS = '225.0.0.38'
MULTICAST_RESPONSE_PORT = 12346
BIND_ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0'

# Transmit packet on all adapters - this part works fine
packet = [ID_STRING].pack("Z*")
addresses = Socket.ip_address_list
addresses.each do |addr|
    next unless addr.pfamily == Socket::PF_INET
    socket = UDPSocket.new
    socket.bind(addr.ip_address, MULTICAST_SEND_PORT)
    socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET, Socket::SO_BROADCAST, true)
    socket.send(packet, 0, MULTICAST_SEND_ADDRESS, MULTICAST_SEND_PORT)
    socket.close
end

# Receive packet - this should work, but doesn't
membership = IPAddr.new(MULTICAST_SEND_ADDRESS).hton + IPAddr.new(BIND_ADDRESS).hton
listen_socket = UDPSocket.new
listen_socket.setsockopt(Socket::IPPROTO_IP, Socket::IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, membership)
listen_socket.bind(BIND_ADDRESS, MULTICAST_RESPONSE_PORT)
packet, addr = listen_socket.recvfrom(1024)
# We never get to this line since there's nothing received
puts packet
```

Comment: Do you have a process on your computer that subscribes to the multicast address? Many switches do IGMP snooping, and they will not deliver multicast to an interfaces where the host has not subscribed to the multicast group. There is also a know IGMP snooping problem with two switches and no mrouter.

Comment: No, there are no services running that listens to that port or address. Since Wireshark/tcpdump on the Linux machine sees the package it must be delivered by the switch to the interface. The main network has a router of course somewhere up the line, and the small network where the device is connected has only one switch. What scenario exactly does the IGMP snooping problem apply and what does it entail?

Comment: Multicast is different than your normal unicast networking. A process wishing to receive multicast must subscribe to a multicast group by sending an IGMP message requesting that traffic to that group be sent to it. Switches used to just send multicast to every interface the way they do broadcast. IGMP snooping has changed that so that switches only send multicast to the interfaces where a host has sent an IGMP join. Switches do not send IGMP to each other, so you need an mrouter, or IGMP querier. See [this question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28301/8499) and answers.

Comment: I think I understand, but if that was the case Wireshark should not get the packet. Also, something I forgot to mention is that my program detects other devices via multicast without problem.

Comment: The `255.255.255.255` address is the Limited Broadcast address, not a multicast address. Broadcasts are delivered to every switch interface.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that and edited my response. However this discussion gave me some ideas and clues and I found the problem. In spite of what the Ruby-documentation say and all code-examples I've found, it seems you can't bind to address '0.0.0.0' on multihomed hosts. When I bound to the actual ip of the correct interface it started working!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem in the end. In spite of what all the code examples I've seen say, it seems you can't bind to address '0.0.0.0' to get all interfaces on a multihomed machine. I don't know if this used to work and has been changed or all examples I've found have only been tested on singlehomed machines, but when I bound the socket to the actual ip of the correct interface it started working.